# Podemos conjugar o imperativo afirmativo nas primeiras e terceiras pessoas?

Tags: conjugações, tempo-verbal

Aprendi na escola que o tempo verbal imperativo não é conjugado nas primeiras pessoas do singular e do plural. Gramáticos atuais também tem questionado o uso da terceira pessoa do plural. Apesar disso tudo, é comum nos depararmos com o uso do imperativo na primeira pessoa, tanto do singular quanto do plural, e também na terceira pessoa do plural. Vejamos abaixo (humm, esse vejamos é imperativo?) alguns exemplos:

```
Alma minha gentil, que te partiste
Tão cedo desta vida descontente, 
Repousa lá no Céu eternamente,   
E viva eu cá na terra sempre triste.                 Luís de Camões
```

"Alma  minha", embora sendo um belo cacófato, é explicado pelos nossos professores como sendo "permissão poética" ou seja, Camões pode, mas eu não. Mais abaixo é que vemos o uso do imperativo na primeira pessoa em **"E viva eu cá na terra"**

Um outro exemplo do imperativo usado na primeira pessoa, agora do plural, é:

- **"*Larguemos as armas* e vamos discutir com calma"**

e a terceira pessoa do plural, por exemplo,

- **"Fiquem eles de guarda na entrada"**

Resumindo a pergunta: de acordo com as normas cultas vigentes em 2017, em quais pessoas podemos conjugar o imperativo afirmativo?

Comment: Nunca existiu imperativo na primeira pessoa do singular.

Comment: e eu viva é subjuntivo. Não é imperativo...

Comment: @Lambie  O "viva eu" usado por Camões é considerado uma forma de optativo.  O poeta estava exprimindo um optativo, não um desejo.  Uma condição forçada, necessária, já que ninguém ordenar ou exortar imperativamente a si próprio.  Nesse caso, "viva eu" não é exatamente a mesma coisa que "que eu viva".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todas os exemplos da pergunta são frases válidas, mas dois deles—“e viva eu cá na terra…” e “fiquem eles de guarda…”—são exemplos do subjuntivo/conjuntivo independente, não do imperativo. O imperativo não existe na primeira pessoa do singular (*viva eu* não é imperativo), e nas terceiras pessoas existe apenas com pronomes de tratamento—*você aí, venha cá; vocês aí, venham cá*.

### Imperativo

Vejamos uma coisa de cada vez. Como observa a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (2014, p. 597):

> Quando empregamos o IMPERATIVO, em geral, temos o intuito de exortar o nosso interlocutor a cumprir a ação indicada pelo verbo.

E ainda segundo a *Nova Gramática* (p. 596), o imperativo existe em todas as pessoas exceto a 1ª do singular (negrito meu):

> **2.** Como no IMPERATIVO o indivíduo que fala se dirige a um interlocutor, **só admite** este modo as pessoas que indicam *aquele a quem se fala:*
>
> *a)* as 2.as pessoas do singular e do plural;
>
> *b)* as 3.as pessoas do singular e do plural, quando o sujeito é expresso por pronome de tratamento, como *você, o senhor, Vossa Senhoria*, etc.;
>
> *c)* a 1.ª pessoa do plural, que no caso denota estar o indivíduo que fala disposto a associar-se ao cumprimento da ordem, conselho ou súplica que dirige a outros.

Nos exemplos “viva eu cá na terra” e “fiquem eles de guarda” os sujeitos—“eu” e “eles”—não indicam a pessoa a quem se fala, logo não são imperativo. Eis exemplos para todas as pessoas admissíveis. Em todos os casos o verbo *esperar* exprime uma exortação direta—que o interlocutor espere:

> 2ª pessoa do singular: ***Espera***, que ele já vem falar contigo.
>   3ª pessoa do singular: ***Espere***, que ele já vem falar com você/ o senhor.
>   1ª pessoa do plural: ***Esperemos***, que ele já vem falar connosco.
>   2ª pessoa do plural: ***Esperai***, que ele já vem falar convosco (pouco usado).
>   3ª pessoa do plural: ***Esperem***, que ele já vem falar com vocês/os senhores.

Na primeira pessoa, o imperativo não existe. Uma pessoa pode fazer exortações diretas a si mesma, mas nesse caso usa a 2ª ou 3ª pessoa do singular—a que preferir usar como tratamento de intimidade—ou ainda a 1ª pessoa do plural:

> Digo eu: *Jacinto, **despacha** lá esta resposta*.
>
> Returco eu: *Calma Jacinto, **vamos** lá a ter calma*

---

### Conjuntivo/Subjuntivo

A confusão entre o imperativo e o presente do subjuntivo/conjuntivo decorre de na primeira e terceiras pessoas as formas do verbo serem iguais nos dois modos—originalmente o imperativo existia apenas na 2ª pessoa; as formas restantes vieram por empréstimo do presente do subjuntivo—e de o conjuntivo também ser usado para exprimir desejos e ordens. Mas diferentemente do imperativo, o conjuntivo não exprime uma ordem direta ao interlocutor. Quando digo “fiquem eles de guarda” não estou a dirigir-me a “eles” nem estou a ordenar ao meu interlocutor que fique de guarda. Vejamos o que diz a *Nova Gramática* (p. 584):

> **Conjuntivo independente**
>
> Empregado em orações absolutas, em orações coordenadas ou em orações principais, o CONJUNTIVO pode exprimir, além das noções imperativas que examinaremos adiante:
>
> *a)* um desejo, um anelo:
>
> > **Chovam** hinos de glória na sua alma! (Antero de Quental, [*Sonetos Completos*, 1890,] 35.)
> >
> > Que as horas **voltem** sempre, as mesmas horas! (Augusto Meyer, [*Poesias*, 1957,] 254.)
>
> *b)* uma hipótese, uma concessão:
>
> > **Seja** a minha agonia uma centelha
> >     De glória!... (Olavo Bilac, [*Tarde*, 1919], 197.)
> >
> > Que a tua música
> >     **seja** o ritmo de uma conquista!
> >     E que o teu ritmo
> >     **seja** a cadência de uma vida nova!
> >      (Francisco José Tenreiro, [Obra Poética, 1967], 62.)
>
> […]
>
> *d)* uma ordem, uma proibição (na 3.ª pessoa):
>
> > Que **levem** tudo no caixão:
> >     A alma e o suporte! (Miguel Torga, [*Cântico do Homem*, 1954], 31.)
> >
> > Que não se **apague** este lume! (Augusto Meyer, [*Poesias*, 1957], 126.)

Os exemplos “fiquem eles de guarda” e “viva eu cá na terra” são formalmente do tipo do Olavo Bilac acima—“seja a minha agonia”—ou seja é do tipo conjuntivo + sujeito, dispensando o *que* que frequentemente antecede o conjuntivo.

Comment: Muito informativa a tua resposta.  Mas o meu comentário de que não se usa o imperativo na terceira pessoa do plural refere-se a "de quem se fala"  e não a "vocês" ou "vossas excelências".  O que me dizes de "Fiquem eles de guarda na entrada"?  Em tempo: "as frases seguinte(s)"  é um "typo" ou é assim em pt-PT?  Também "das silva"

Comment: /Que fiquem de guarda na entrada/ ou /Fiquem de guarda na entrada/ E não: fiquem eles.

Comment: @Lambie Podemos sim dizer "fiquem eles de guarda na entrada".  "Não, vocês já trabalharam bastante.  Figuem eles agora."

Comment: @Centaurus Tinha-me passado o teu exemplo do "fiquem eles de guarda". Já tratei isso.

Comment: @Centaurus O Houaiss indica o imperativo só para as segundas pessoas e 1ª do plural, mas na tabela deles 2ª pessoa é tu, vós e pronomes de tratamento. Ou seja por *segunda pessoa* eles querem dizer 'segunda pessoa do discurso', que inclui a 2ª pessoa gramatical e os pronomes de tratamento, que são 3ª gramatical. Talvez os tais gramáticos que referes que excluem a 3ª pessoa do imperativo se refiram à 3ª pessoa do discurso (ele, ela, etc.)?

Comment: @Jacinto   Note que na pergunta eu cito o não uso do imperativo para a  terceira pessoa do plural, não do singular,  embora eu concorde contigo que a terceira pessoa do plural possa também ser "as pessoas com quem falamos" (vocês)